# How can I create more polygons for purposes of sculpting?

Tags: mesh

Whenever I look at why my Sculpting isn't working I find answers like :

> Select the grab tool (G) and ensure the brush is large enough.
>
> To sculpt properly, you need enough polygons to operate on.
>
> If you don't have them, consider retopologizing via the remesher
> option in the sculpting mode and experiment with different voxel-size
> levels (smaller makes more polygons) of to find the outcome you want!
>
> Don't go too low too quickly or you will lose the ability to make
> coarse changes to the sculpt: One's workflow should begin coarse and
> become fine over time when sculpting in detail-passes!

But how do I do that?
Any help appreciated, Nathan

Answer (score 1):

If you are in the sculpting workspace, you can find the remesh button here:
[image]
As mentioned in the text you copied, if you click the arrow next to remesh, it will open up a menu allowing you to adjust the Voxel Size, which will control how many polygons you end up with.

Another option for adding more polygons to your mesh is the Dyntopo button (directly to the left of the remesh button), which has a "Detail Flood fill" option in the panel. This allows you to set a resolution and will convert your mesh into polygons of that size.

Comment: Note: Shift+R lets you visually adjust the voxel size. This reduces the likelihood that you will accidentally use a voxel size that is too small, which creates a lot of geometry and freezes Blender. CTRL+R is the shortcut for the Remesh operation.